# UTF-8 support in Corda inside the flow

Tags: corda

I have a problem when I'm calling a web service inside my flow in Corda. it doesn't support UTF-8 and when request goes out of the flow the encoding will be changed. How can I enable it?

Comment: interesting. can you set encoding to 'UTF-8' in JavaCompile Option? and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

the problem solved by setting the environment variable "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" to "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8". Actually it should be able to be set with a property option in Corda too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the encoding value in the environment variable. It can be applied directly to javaCompile options in gradle:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```